# How does createDataPartition function from caret package split data?

Tags: r, subset, r-caret, data-partitioning

From the documentation:

> For bootstrap samples, simple random sampling is used.
>
> For other data splitting, the random sampling is done within the levels of y
> when y is a factor in an attempt to balance the class distributions within
> the splits.
>
> For numeric y, the sample is split into groups sections based on percentiles
> and sampling is done within these subgroups.
>
> For createDataPartition, the number of percentiles is set via the groups
> argument.

I don't understand why this "balance" thing is needed. I think I understand it superficially, but any additional insight would be really helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It means, if you have a data set `ds` with 10000 rows

```
set.seed(42)
ds <- data.frame(values = runif(10000))
```

with 2 "classes" with unequal distribution (9000 vs 1000)

```
ds$class <- c(rep(1, 9000), rep(2, 1000))
ds$class <- as.factor(ds$class)
table(ds$class)
#    1    2 
# 9000 1000
```

you can create a sample, which tries to maintain the ratio / "balance" of the `factor` classes.

```
dpart <- createDataPartition(ds$class, p = 0.1, list = F)
dsDP <- ds[dpart, ]
table(dsDP$class)
#   1   2 
# 900 100
```