# Splitting data sets in r programming

Tags: r

I'm trying to split data

```
Datasplit <- createDataPartition(tele$Tele, p=0.7, list= FALSE)
```

But get an error message

```
Error in createDataPartition(tele$Tele, p=0.8, list = FALSE): y must have at least 2 data points.
```

What does it mean?

Comment: duplicate? [How does createDataPartition function from caret package split data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709722/how-does-createdatapartition-function-from-caret-package-split-data)

Comment: Why am I getting the error message?

Comment: Since we don't know what your data is, how could we know why you are getting an error message? It seems like you are passing fewer than 2 data points to a function which is expecting at least 2. Please give a [mcve]. See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248) for what this would mean in R.

Comment: share `str(tele$Tele)`, it seems that either you have less then 2 `factor levels`, or you have just one observation in `tele`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does createDataPartition function from caret package split data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709722/how-does-createdatapartition-function-from-caret-package-split-data)